# Trying to use regex (or R) to turn press releases into a dataset

Tags: r, regex, parsing, text, dataset

I'm working on a project to turn [press releases](https://www.defense.gov/OIR/Airstrikes/?Page=13) from Operation Inherent Resolve which detail airstrikes against ISIS in Syria and Iraq into a usable dataset. So far we've been handcoding everything but it just takes insanely long.

Every press release is structured like this:

> **November 23, 2016**
> Military Strikes Continue Against ISIL Terrorists in Syria and Iraq
> U.S. Central Command
>
> **SOUTHWEST ASIA, November 23, 2016** - On Nov. 22, Coalition military forces  conducted 17 strikes against ISIL terrorists in Syria and Iraq. In Syria, Coalition military forces conducted 11 strikes using attack, bomber, fighter, and remotely piloted aircraft against ISIL targets. Additionally in Iraq,  Coalition military forces conducted six strikes coordinated with and in support of the Government of Iraq using attack, bomber, fighter, and remotely piloted aircraft against ISIL targets.
>
> The following is a summary of the strikes conducted since the last press release:
>
> **Syria**
>
> - Near Abu Kamal, one strike destroyed an oil rig.
> - Near Ar Raqqah, four strikes engaged an ISIL tactical unit, destroyed two vehicles, an oil tanker truck, an oil pump, and a VBIED, and damaged a road.
>
> **Iraq**
>
> - Near Rawah, one strike engaged an ISIL tactical unit and destroyed a vehicle, a mortar system, and a weapons cache.
> - Near Mosul, four strikes engaged three ISIL tactical units, destroyed >six ISIL-held buildings, a mortar system, a vehicle, a weapons cache, a supply cache, and an artillery system, and damaged five supply routes, and a bridge.
>
> more text I don't need, about 5 exceptions where they amend previous reports I'll just fix by hand, and then the next report

What I'm trying to do is pull out just the date of the strike and how many strikes per city for both Iraq and Syria and reformat that information into a proper dataset organized as one row per date, like this:

```
        Rawah   Mosul   And  So  On
1/1/2014  1         4
1/2/2014  2         5
```

The bad: There's a different number of cities listed for each country in each press release, and a different number of strikes listed each time.

The good: Everything one of these press releases is worded **exactly** the same.
The string "SOUTHWEST ASIA," is always in front of the date
A 4 space indent followed by the word "Near" are always in front of the city
The city and a comma are always in front of the number of strikes
The number of strikes are always in front of the word "airstrike" or "airstrikes"

The question is whether it's possible to make a regex to either copy/cut everything matching those criteria in order or just delete everything else. I think to grab the arbitrary number of cities (with unknown names) and unknown numbers of strikes it would have to be based on copying/saving everything next to the unchanging markers.

I've tried using notepad++'s find/replace function with something like `*(foobar)*` but I can only match one thing at a time and when I try to replace everything but the matched string it just deletes the whole file instead of protecting every instance of the matching string.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest searching by using `Near (.*?),`. You can back-reference with \1.

I did a quick scan of the documents, and it seems the more recent ones change a bit of the format, adding "Strikes at [country]" rather than your example of just "[country]". But each one lists the city in a Near [city], format.

This would grab you the cities, of course, but you would have to do some pretty hacky things to get the number of strikes, since there doesn't seem to be a standard for that.

If you are only dealing with the records that have your formatting, try `Near (.*?), (.*? )` and you should get the spelled out number of strikes per city by referencing \2, and the city by referencing \1.

So, if you were to find and replace in Notepad++, you would use something like `.*Near (.*?), (.*? ).*` as your find, and something like `\1 -- \2` as your replace. From there you would need to draft up a small script to translate the spelled numbers to digits, and output those where they need to go. The pattern `\w* \d{1,2}, \d{4}` will match a date in the long format, something else you could pipe into a python script or something to construct your table of data. Sorry I couldn't help more there!

Comment: All of the press releases I've been assigned follow more or less this exact format, at least when it comes to the relevant bits. The date always follows "SOUTHWEST ASIA," and the city plus number of strikes follows the word "Near" which itself has four blankspaces in front of it.

Comment: @D3SL The "SOUTHWEST ASIA" part is pretty irrelevant, since you don't care what happened per country, only per city. Does this answer not solve the problem? Aside from not giving the number in digit format, I'm not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: I'm building a dataset where columns are the number of strikes per city and rows are the date. I'm starting with a plain text file of almost every press release (like the one above) from 2016 at the top going back to 2014 at the bottom.

The date is always between `SOUTHWEST ASIA,` and `-`, and the city name plus number of strikes is always between `....Near` (periods for blankspaces) and `Airstrike(s)`. Because the stuff I'm grabbing is always different I think using a regex or R-function based off the fixed strings will work most reliably.

Comment: @D3SL Ah, okay, so you need the date as well. I'll update my answer in a bit with that. Are these articles always posted the day after the strike, or is there sometimes a break?

Comment: As near as I can tell every strike either happened the day before the press release date or started the day before the press release and continued to the day of the press release local-time, which is irrelevant because I'd just code that for the day it started (ie day before the press release).

Comment: @D3SL I updated this a bit ago, does this work for you?

Comment: I tried both but the city+strike regex kept choking on things like `ar raqqah` counting as two words vs `mosul` counting as one. I did wind up finding another solution involving lookahead and lookbehind that works robustly in all cases. I just need to make it work with R now. Thanks for trying to help Kirkpatt